# Instant messenger streaming with libVLC python wrapper

Tags: python, streaming, vlc, instant-messaging, libvlc

I'm trying to develop an instant messenger client that supports video streaming. I am working with the libVLC wrapper for Python. Most basic functions of an IM client are already there, my problem comes with the video streaming. I've been able to do basic tests like streaming a video and playing it in a tkinter form with my own code. But when it comes to streaming to many users, and recieving many streams from other users I'm completely lost. I'd appreciate any help you can give me, maybe this is not the right way to do it and you can point me out the direction I should take, everything helps as I am not a very experienced programmer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: might I suggest the vlc developper forums?  The maintainers really monitor and respond to questions http://forum.videolan.org/viewforum.php?f=32  They also respond quickly to emails on their email list http://www.videolan.org/developers/lists.html Although some of them are in France, so there may be a time delay before they respond.

Comment: I'll check there and see what happens, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will be easy.
http://wiki.videolan.org/VideoLan_VideoConference#See_also might give you some clues as to directions to try...

Comment: thanks for your answer, a VLC developer answered me and told me that the easiest way to do it was setting up a VPN server (the other solution was implementing teredo tunneling myself in my client, way over my skills and needs). Each client now is connected to a VPN server and it's pretty much like streaming over my private network. By the way, my school project was finished and I got a good grade.